# Cannot get 301 redirect to work in .htacess

Tags: redirect

I have been looking through the various threads related to .htacess 301 redirects and I simply cannot find a solution to my problem. I have added this into the .htaccess which was previously an empty file...

redirect 301 http://www.architekogp.com/index.html http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php

The .htaccess is located in the architekogp.com root folder (public_html/.htaccess). I am not sure if the .html to .php is causing the issue? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: try redirect 301 /index.html http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Wait so all all your code in .htaccess is: 
     redirect 301 http://www.architekogp.com/index.html http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php

Correct?

Comment: If your putting the .htacces in the architekogp's files you could use this: Redirect 301 / http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php

Comment: Yes, however I just realised I probably need to add code to the old html too? I used a 301 redirect generator and it only instructed me to put that code in the .htaccess.

Comment: Well are the two website running off the same hosts? Or different ones?

Comment: Same host, the new site is an addonn domain.

Comment: I just got it to kind of redirect, however to the address...
http://www.owenprescott.com/index.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.php......

using this (redirect 301 / http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php)

Comment: Well there are two things that you could do. One being in the index of architeckogp's page put: <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url"> in the head or you could use the method of this: Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/

Comment: Okay, tell me when that works, just make sure you set the seconds to 0

Comment: I will try the meta redirect now. Nothing.
It does attempt to redirect with your suggestion though it adds a continuous index.php loop to the end. Do I need to add anything to the owenprescott.com root folder? Perhaps there is some permission issue?

Comment: Thanks I did not change the seconds, it works now. Will google redirect the rank using the meta method?

Comment: It works so do you still need it? The code is to long, here is the meta tag I included...
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.owenprescott.com/index.php">

Comment: Wait so its your site doing what you want it to do now?

Comment: Yes it is redirecting to my new website. I am also now removing everything but the meta tag you suggested so that the old content does not load before redirecting to the new page.

Comment: Okay cool, glad I could help, just make sure to mark your question answered. Have a good day

Comment: I have clicked the up arrow on your answer which I assume means complete so thanks.

Comment: There should be a green check by it. Thanks.